# Drawing with multiple layers on Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I have googled for a while and can't seem to get the info I need.  To draw a simple line on an ImageView, I use the code like this.

```
dh = ivSpeed.getHeight();
dw = ivSpeed.getWidth();
bivSpeed = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
civSpeed = new Canvas(bivSpeed);
ivSpeed.setImageBitmap(bivSpeed);

civSpeed.drawLine(50,50,400,400,maxpaint);
```

I now need to draw using two layers.  The bottom layer will have as many as 1000 lines.  I then want to make this bottom layer almost like a background...or whatever approach I need.  I want to draw it only once.  I will then have a second layer in which I will be drawing and deleting.  The method I traditionally use to delete is

```
civSpeed.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

I don't want to delete the 1000 lines on the bottom layer and then redraw them everytime I delete and redraw on the top level.  What is the best approach for me to take to accomplish this?

Comment: See LayerDrawable docs

Comment: I just found the perfect answer for me.  Using a relative layout and putting the images on top of each other with the background set as transparent.  Works great!